# Why does nunjucks fail silently on bad syntax while compiling, or bad data while rendering?

Tags: javascript, nunjucks

While editing my templates, if I make a mistake, say for example I leave off a closing tag, as in...

```html
{% if variable %}
  Notice there is no closing tag within this template!
```

When compiling this, nunjucks seems to remain silent. I don't see an exception or console.log. Is this the intended experience? Is there a config flag to turn on "die loudly if anything is wrong"?

The same applies during rendering. If my template is fine, but I render it with data that does not match, it seems to silently fail. Is it supposed to fail quietly, not throw any exceptions, not log to the console?

Comment: Please give an example of bad syntax and the rendered result. I'd expect template syntax errors to cause a server-side error message, so please provide a [mre].

Comment: @ChrisG I know right? That's what I would expect, too! That's my question. Why doesn't it? Anyway I edited the question to provide a single specific example of bad syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It's all my fault. Nunjucks *does* throw exceptions for this sort of thing. The exception was being lost because of how I was using the jQuery promises library. The source explains it very nicely...

```
// Support: Promises/A+ section 2.3.3.3.4.1
// https://promisesaplus.com/#point-61
// Ignore post-resolution exceptions
if ( depth + 1 >= maxDepth ) {
```

The idea is, if the `.then()` handler of a promise throws an exception, the promises library catches that exception. The promise's `.fail()` handler is then called. If the promise doesn't have a `fail` handler, that's when the exception is "lost". By using promises, I bought in to the error handling story of promises.

It wasn't nunjucks' fault.